# Android Retrofit:Steps to Migrate from Retrofit 1.9 to Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit, retrofit2, asynccallback

i am currently using retrofit 1.9 where i am having many issues using it like i get retrofit pipe broken error and many stuffs so basically now i am planning to migrate from 1.9 to 2.0 but i am confused and totally frustuated trying different steps to come over it . i would be very much thankfull to you guys if you could please help me in overcoming it . I have my retrofit 1.9 code for post and get request below . please help me with the steps to change my code

1> Here is my only 1 retrofit dependencies that is currently being used 
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
   so what do i change for dependencies

2>My retrofit interface for post and get

```
 @POST("/trinkingu/operations.php")
    void createNewSeekerProfile( @Query("module") String module,
                                 @Query("action") String action,
            @Body SeekerProfileModel body, Callback<Response> callback);


@GET("/synkku/services.php")
void getAlljobPosts(@Query("module") String module,
                    @Query("action") String action,
                    @Query("key") String key,
                    @Query("value") String value, Callback<ArrayList<JobsModel>> response);
```

3>My Retrofit Helper class

```
public void addNewSeekerProfile(String module,String action,SeekerProfileModel seekerProfileModel) {
    //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
    //Creating a RestAdapter
    System.out.println("##coming here");
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Allconstants.MAIN_URL) //Setting the Root URL
            .build(); //Finally building the adapter
    //Creating object for our interface
    RetroApiInterface api = adapter.create(RetroApiInterface.class);

    //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
    api.createNewSeekerProfile(
            module,
            action,
            seekerProfileModel,
            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
                    TypedInput body = response.getBody();
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(body.in()));
                        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            out.append(line);
                            out.append(newLine);
                        }

                        // Prints the correct String representation of body.
                        System.out.println(out);
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"result"+out,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"error"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

and here is get

```
public void getAllMyPostedJobs(String inputKey, String inputValue) {
        //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
        //Creating a rest adapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Allconstants.MAIN_URL)
                .build();

        //Creating an object of our api interface
        RetroApiInterface api = adapter.create(RetroApiInterface.class);

        api.getAlljobPosts(Allconstants.JOBS, Allconstants.ACTION_GET_ALL_MY_POSTEDJOBS, inputKey, inputValue, new Callback<ArrayList<JobsModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ArrayList<JobsModel> jobsModels, Response response) {
                if (mResultCallback != null)
                    mResultCallback.notifySuccess(jobsModels, response);
                System.out.println("###successfull ");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if (mResultCallback != null)
                    mResultCallback.notifyError(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

please help me in making the changes now inorder to migrate to 2.0
Your help will much more appreciated
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I give you all code. Once my laptop is available. Till then change dependecy to compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

Comment: how much time will it take ? @Divyesh

Comment: just 10 min, i got laptop. i am working on it.

Comment: Is there any solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Compile:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

create Interface:

```
public interface ItemAPI {

@GET("/synkku/services.php")
call<JobsModel>  getAlljobPosts(@Query("module") String module,
                    @Query("action") String action,
                    @Query("key") String key,
                    @Query("value") String value);

                    }
```

create class:

```
public class Apiclient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "YOUR BASE_URL";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Now, in your activity:

```
ItemAPI itemAPI = Apiclient.getClient().create(ItemAPI.class);
Call<JobsModel> call=itemAPI.getAlljobPosts(Allconstants.JOBS, Allconstants.ACTION_GET_ALL_MY_POSTEDJOBS, inputKey, inputValue);

call.enqueue(new Callback<JobsModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JobsModel> call, Response<JobsModel> response) {
        try {
            HERE YOU CAN GET JoBSModel VIA RESPONSE.BODY."your model method name"
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedAfterRetry(Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: how about post with arraylist as like i did in my above 1.9 code?

Comment: I don't understand. In code, response.body gives you ArrayList of JobsModel

Comment: @GET("/synkku/services.php")
    Call<JobsModel> getAlljobPosts(@Query("module") String module,
                                   @Query("action") String action,
                                   @Query("key") String key,
                                   @Query("value") String value);

Comment: posted above please check

Answer (score 0):

public class JobsModel implements Serializable {

```
@SerializedName("_id")
private String _id = null;
@SerializedName("posted_by")
private String userId = null;
@SerializedName("company_name")
private String companyName = null;
@SerializedName("position")
private String position = null;
@SerializedName("eligiblity")
private String eligiblity = null;
@SerializedName("experience")
private String experience = null;
@SerializedName("interview_from_date")
private String interviewFromDate = null;
@SerializedName("interview_to_date")
private String interviewToDate = null;
@SerializedName("interview_frm_timing")
private String interviewTimeFrom = null;
@SerializedName("interview_to_timing")
private String interviewTimeTo = null;
@SerializedName("describtion")
private String desc = null;
@SerializedName("skills")
private String skills = null;
@SerializedName("interview_location")
private String interviewLocation = null;
@SerializedName("interview_lat")
private float lat;
@SerializedName("interview_lon")
private float lon;
@SerializedName("contact_person")
private String contactPerson = null;
@SerializedName("contact_phone")
private String contactPhone = null;
@SerializedName("contact_email")
private String contactMail = null;
@SerializedName("total_vocancies")
private int totalVocancies;
@SerializedName("posted_on")
private String postedOn;
@SerializedName("currently_active")
private String currently_active;
@SerializedName("sal_pckg")
private String salPckg;

public JobsModel(String _id, String userId, String companyName, String position, String eligiblity,
                 String experience, String interviewFromDate, String interviewToDate, String interviewTimeFrom, String interviewTimeTo,
                 String desc, String skills, String interviewLocation,
                 String contactPerson, String contactPhone, String contactMail, int totalVocancies, String postedOn, String isActive,String salPckg) {
    this._id=_id;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.position = position;
    this.eligiblity = eligiblity;
    this.experience = experience;
    this.interviewFromDate = interviewFromDate;
    this.interviewToDate = interviewToDate;
    this.interviewTimeFrom = interviewTimeFrom;
    this.interviewTimeTo = interviewTimeTo;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.skills = skills;
    this.interviewLocation = interviewLocation;
    this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
    this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
    this.contactMail = contactMail;
    this.totalVocancies = totalVocancies;
    this.postedOn=postedOn;
    this.currently_active =isActive;
    this.salPckg=salPckg;
}

public String getSalPckg() {
    return salPckg;
}

public void setSalPckg(String salPckg) {
    this.salPckg = salPckg;
}

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public String getEligiblity() {
    return eligiblity;
}

public void setEligiblity(String eligiblity) {
    this.eligiblity = eligiblity;
}

public String getExperience() {
    return experience;
}

public void setExperience(String experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

public String getInterviewFromDate() {
    return interviewFromDate;
}

public void setInterviewFromDate(String interviewFromDate) {
    this.interviewFromDate = interviewFromDate;
}

public String getInterviewToDate() {
    return interviewToDate;
}

public void setInterviewToDate(String interviewToDate) {
    this.interviewToDate = interviewToDate;
}

public String getInterviewTimeFrom() {
    return interviewTimeFrom;
}

public void setInterviewTimeFrom(String interviewTimeFrom) {
    this.interviewTimeFrom = interviewTimeFrom;
}

public String getInterviewTimeTo() {
    return interviewTimeTo;
}

public void setInterviewTimeTo(String interviewTimeTo) {
    this.interviewTimeTo = interviewTimeTo;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getSkills() {
    return skills;
}

public void setSkills(String skills) {
    this.skills = skills;
}

public String getInterviewLocation() {
    return interviewLocation;
}

public void setInterviewLocation(String interviewLocation) {
    this.interviewLocation = interviewLocation;
}

public float getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(float lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public float getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(float lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}

public String getContactPerson() {
    return contactPerson;
}

public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
    this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
}

public String getContactPhone() {
    return contactPhone;
}

public void setContactPhone(String contactPhone) {
    this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
}

public String getContactMail() {
    return contactMail;
}

public void setContactMail(String contactMail) {
    this.contactMail = contactMail;
}

public int getTotalVocancies() {
    return totalVocancies;
}

public void setTotalVocancies(int totalVocancies) {
    this.totalVocancies = totalVocancies;
}

public String getPostedOn() {
    return postedOn;
}

public void setPostedOn(String postedOn) {
    this.postedOn = postedOn;
}

public String getCurrently_active() {
    return currently_active;
}

public void setCurrently_active(String currently_active) {
    this.currently_active = currently_active;
}
```

}